# Apply different scaling factor to subsets of rows in a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, tibble

I generating a dataframe by combining a load of csv's into one. I generate a path column, which corresponds to the ID of each CSV, and then aim to do simple math transformations to scale the path column into the timestamp for each csv (each csv is data from a particular time in an experiment). The combined_files tibble has 14 columns and path is the first.

I have some data where I have a gap of 0.5 hours between path 1-7 and path 8-100 (1-7 corresponds to the first 336 rows of my dataframe). I am trying to convert the path for 1-7 to time in hours using

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
files <- stringr::str_sort(files, numeric = TRUE)
files
combined_files <- bind_rows(lapply(files, fread))

combined_files <- readr::read_csv(files, id = "path") %>%
  mutate(path = str_remove(path, "cap_data_"))%>%
  mutate(path = str_remove(path, ".csv"))
combined_files$path <- as.numeric(combined_files$path)

(combined_files[combined_files[c(1:336), 1]] - 1)*0.5
```

and then do the same transformation on the remaining rows, just shifted by 0.5 hours:

```
(combined_files[combined_files[c(1:336), 1]] - 1)*0.5
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns with `combined_files[c(1:336), 1]`.
x `combined_files[c(1:336), 1]` must be logical, numeric, or character, not a <tbl_df/tbl/data.frame> object.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Edit: an example from my data is too large to attach, so here is a table with similar properties:
|path|p1|p2|
|:---|:-:|-:|
|1|10|20|
|1|20|30|
|1|30|54|
|2|10|20|
|2|20|30|
|2|30|54|
|3|10|20|
|3|20|30|
|3|30|54|

In this example, I would want to change the values for path between 1 and 2 to be (i-1)*0.5 (converting into hours, where path = 1 is t = 0) and path = 3 to a value of 2 (through (i -1)*0.5 +1 (where i is the value of path for each row)
I found a bad way to do it - just split the tibble and then rebind it, but if anyone has any route to avoid splitting that would be amazing!

```
combined_files_1st <- subset(combined_files, combined_files$path < 7.5 )
combined_files_2nd <- subset(combined_files, combined_files$path > 7)
combined_files_1st$path <- (combined_files_1st$path - 1)*0.5
combined_files_2nd$path <- (combined_files_2nd$path-1)*0.5 +0.5

combined_join <- rbind(combined_files_1st, combined_files_2nd)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused ... you have two blocks of code, one that ends with `combined_files <- bind_rows(lapply(files, fread))` and the next that starts with `combined_files <- readr::read_csv(files, id = "path") %>% ...`, the second clearly overwriting the first. Which is it? Also ... can you please share sample representative data? The use of `dput(head(combined_files))` is a start, though make sure the sample has enough variability to demonstrate what you need.

Comment: It seems a bit fragile for the sole determination of how to adjust being based on row numbers, I think it might be safer to determine adjustment based on the "index" you mentioned. If your first column is named `quux` (I don't know what it really is), you can do something like `mutate(adj = case_when(index %in% 1:7 ~ 0.5, index %in% 8:100 ~ 0.75, TRUE ~ 1))` (I made up 0.75 and 1 for the example).

Comment: @r2evans. You are correct! Apologies, I had copied this from an old script which was very messy. I only need the second section. In terms of your suggestion below - thank you! How would I make this give varied values within the blocks? So I want index 1 to 7 to be 0 to 3.5, and then from 8 onwards should start from 8.5 in steps of 0.5. Apologies if this is obvious!

Comment: Use [edit] facilities to include revision in your question as well as adding a data-object that can be used to test an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike base matrices/data.frames the `[` operator doesn't subset a vector from a tibble if you ask for a single column, it'll still be a tibble. You'll have to use `[[`, `$`, or [`dplyr::pull`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html).

Untested, but this would be the 'tidyversiest' way (using the base pipe):

```
(combined_files[combined_files[1:336, 1] |> dplyr::pull()] - 1)*0.5
```

Comment: I would like to mention that `combined_files[combined_files[1:336, 1]` is not very `{tidyverse}`-like.

Comment: Agree to that, I just meant out of the tibble-to-vector options.

Comment: Hi @PBulls - thanks for your response! When I run this, it appears to act on all values in the path column, and then creates 336 columns called path with the same value - apologies, not really sure why.